# Debugging the init() method in a Java servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

From what I know about how a Tomcat server works, is that if you have a Java servlet in your web application, the `init()` method is called whenever the server starts up.

In that case, how can I debug the `init()` method? Putting a break point clearly doesn't work, and for some reason `System.out.println` statements also do not yield any output on my server console.

I have checked that the correct web app (`.war`) is deployed and it extracts correctly in the `webapps` folder of my Tomcat server.

Comment: Breakpoints and `println()` methods should work. Can you post some code ?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis has answered the question.

Comment: I took your statements to mean that breakpoints do not work on the `init()` method even when the servlet was initialized. Yes Sotirios' solution should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me like your deployment descriptor servlet declaration doesn't have an `load-on-startup` value bigger than 0. If you have omitted that element, the `Servlet` will only be initialized when the container deems that it should handle a request. Until then, the `init` method is not called.

By providing the `load-on-startup` value, like so

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

You are telling the container to initialize the `Servlet` right away, therefore invoking your `init` method on startup, rather than when the first request for that servlet arrives.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct, the init() method is not called when server startsup.
**It is called only once and it is called during the FIRST CALL TO YOUR SERVLET** to which the same init() method belongs.

As there is one init() for each Serlvet, init() for respective servlet is called when you call the servlet for first time. i.e After container loads the servlet and instantiates it then init() method is called.

Either do,

- Load on startup in web.xml for servlet
- Give call to serlvet(after first call you should see println statement in console)